# Android BottomNavigationView remove tint from icons

Tags: android, menu

I am fairly new to Android development, and I struggle a bit with t building the UI and its design.

I added a bottom navigation view like so:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    style="@style/BottomMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

And created the menu layout as follows:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_control_panels_icon"
        android:tooltipText="Control panels"
        android:title="CONTROL PANELS"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_devices_icon"
        android:tooltipText="Devices"
        android:title="DEVICES"/>
</menu>
```

Now, my problem is with the icons. I want the icons to have a circle behind them, whose color changes when the menu item is selected.

After some research, I found I can use the following code to achieve this:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/purple" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/collection"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#208FF7" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/collection"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And I even created a custom style to make sure the text's color doesn't change:

```xml
<style name="BottomMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="enforceTextAppearance">true</item>
    <item name="enforceMaterialTheme">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

But in the design preview and the build, the icons are small and the colors are incorrect:
[image: Design preview]

The selected item has no color, and the other item is black for some reason.

When I added `<item name="itemIconTint" />` to the custom style, I got the desired result (though still small icons) but it still doesn't work when I build and install the application.

So, is there a way to remove the tint from the icon? Or even a better way to achieve what I want?

This is the desired result:
[image: Desired result]